# would you more readily explain the explanations about the articles?

Tags: articles

The automobile has changed our way of life.( ***the* is used for the class itself)**

automobiles have changed our way of life.( automobiles includes all representatives **in the class)**

but not An automobile has changed our way of life( **An** is interpreted here as indefinite **a**)

The madrigal is popular.
(being popular is characteristic of madrigrals)
Madrigals are popular.
(being popular is normal for madrigrals)
*A madrigal is popular.
(being popular is required for madrigrals)
**... and of course this last conclusion is wrong, producing the star.**

Would you possibly more simple explain the bold parts? and especially I couldn't understand what exactly the word *class* means here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *class* they mean everything that can be classified as an automobile, in this case. Referring to something as a class, means to you include all its counterparts in your classification and refer to them collectively as a group > a class.

This can be achieved with a bare plural:

> Bats are nocturnal creatures.

Or with a definite singular noun:

> The automobile has changed our way of life.

In reference to animals, plants, etc., a definite singular verb suffices to single out its entire general species, or more specifically its genus:

> The bat is a nocturnal creature.
>
> The vampire bat can feed on its host without being detected.

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, would anyone please give me explanations for the other bold parts?

Comment: The asterisk (*) is traditionally used to mark sentences as ungrammatical. That's what they mean by "producing the star."